# Interstitial ad with admob at gameOverScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob, interstitial

I have searched the internet high and low for direction regarding adding an interstitial admob ad at the game over scene with SpriteKit when using swift.

The google documentation still uses Obj-C.

What I have gathered so far is that I need to initialize the ad in the viewController and then call it from the game over scene?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to find the answer in a roundabout way. By using NSNotificationcenter you can call a function from the viewcontroller that will load the and run the interstitial add.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you found/used to resolve your issue? Might come handy in the future when someone faces the same problem.

Comment: I updated the question to show the solution

Comment: Thanks! FYI: you could also post your findings as an answer to your question and even accept your own answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the best, thanks

Answer (score 1):

### **Updated solution**

I set in the view controller in the viewdidload

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"loadAndShow", name: "loadAndShow", object: nil)
```

then I have a separate function (in the viewcontroller ) called loadAndShow ... which will load and show the interstitial ad if ready

then from the gameOverScene, I call

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadAndShow", object: nil)
```

which will run the function from the VC to present the ad. Works perfectly.