# How to add AdMob to the endscreen?

Tags: java, android, admob, surfaceview

How can I ad Admob to the GameOver Screen?
I searched a lot but I didn`t found very much!

My MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GameView gView; 

        @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gView);
    }
  }
```

and my GameView:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

      private boolean gameOver;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gameOver = false;
      }


       @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      if(!gameOver)
        {
          drawGame(canvas);
        }
        else
        {
          //add Admob Banner here to the Screen
          drawGameOver(canvas);
        }

      }

     public void drawGame(Canvas can){
       }

      public void drawGameOver(Canvas can){
        }



    }
```

My whole game is drawn on the canvas. But I want only schow AdMob at the GameOver screen.
How can I show it there?
I found something here:
[Interstitial ad with admob at gameOverScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494495/interstitial-ad-with-admob-at-gameoverscene)
but I don't think its  a solution for me. Or how can I implement this to my code?

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add banner ads programmatically and show or hide them in your game's screens via a listener. Modify your code as follows, make sure you replace "yourAdUnitId" with your real adUnit Id

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyAdListener{
private GameView gView; 
AdView adView;
    @Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 gView = new GameView(this);

AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;

    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    double density = dm.density * 160;
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
        adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
    } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
        adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
    } else { // > 320 X 50
        adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
    }       
    adView = new AdView(this);
     adView.setAdUnitId("yourAdUnitId"); 
     adView.setAdSize(adSize);
     adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);     
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    layout.addView(gView);
    layout.addView(adView, adViewParams);
    setContentView(layout);
}

@Override
  public void showBannerAd() {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  });
}
  }



public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

private boolean gameOver;
private Activity mActivity;

public GameView(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    myAdListener = (MyAdListener)activity;
    gameOver = false;

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(!gameOver){

        drawGame(canvas);

    }
    else
    {

        //show admob
       myAdListener.showBannerAd();
        drawGameOver(canvas);

    }

}

public void drawGame(Canvas can){

}

public void drawGameOver(Canvas can){

}

public interface MyAdListener{
public void showBannerAd();
}

}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your Help! But I got the Error in this Line: `layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`  the Error: `The constructor ViewPager.LayoutParams(int, int) is undefined` so I changed it to: `layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`. I got no Errors but I see nothing. Is the ViewGroup wrong?

Comment: Seems you are importing the wrong classes. Using my code,  Import  "android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;" instead of "android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;"  Let me know if you have further problems. Thanks

Comment: Yeah! You were right! I got the wrong imports. Now it works but not perfect. The 'onDraw' methode from the View overdraw the banner. When I click on the top of the Screen the browser starts, but I see no Banner. So I think it is behind the Canvas. I tried to declare the 'layout' variable as public an call in the View `activity.layout.draw(canvas)` but got the Error: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` . I don't think its a good solution. Have you any Idea what I can do?

Comment: It's a common problem. The solution is to set a background color for the adview. E.g adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);. I've updated my answer. Let me know if you still face issues

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an `AdView` into your `main_activity.xml` like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then try this following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GameView gView;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View _view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_activity, null);

        mAdView = (AdView) _view.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        gView = new GameView(this);

        setContentView(gView);

    }

    public void showBanner(){

        AdRequest _adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mAdView.loadAd(_adRequest);

    }

}

public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    private boolean gameOver;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public GameView(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);

        gameOver = false;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if(!gameOver){

            drawGame(canvas);

        }
        else
        {

            //add Admob here to the Screen
            drawGameOver(canvas);

        }

    }

    public void drawGame(Canvas can){

    }

    public void drawGameOver(Canvas can){

        mActivity.showBanner();

    }

}
```

For more information, take a look this link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: This is wrong. So how does the adview get attached to gView?   First you define main_activity.xml to contain the adview then you go ahead with         setContentView(gView); So wrong :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got the Error: "The method showBanner() is undefined for the type Activity" when I try to start the "showBanner()" method in the GameView. Any Idea why? I have saved all changes in the activiy and also tryed to declaraed the Method "showBanner()" as Static but same Error.

Comment: @ArturGräfenstein This solution is wrong. See my answer and ask questions if you need further help. Thanks